# vimeo oAth authentication through iPhone app

Tags: ipad, authentication, vimeo

I have an iPad app and need to integrate vimeo to it. I'm in the initial stages of integrating it to my app. I first need to authenticate my app through vimeo.

I've gone through the steps for authentication in documentation and I'm able to pass through first 2 steps:

Request Token:
    http://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token

User Authorization:
    http://vimeo.com/oauth/authorize

But unable to get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` through last step:

Access Token:
    http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token

Vimeo redirects to callback url instead of going back to the app which is fine until I get verifier and authorization token. But once I use these to get `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`, console shows following error message:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x18146180 {
    NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=141b4ff56c48dc5d03501297bde85ebc&oauth_verifier=land-1886924229, 
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token?oauth_token=141b4ff56c48dc5d03501297bde85ebc&oauth_verifier=land-1886924229, 
    NSUnderlyingError=0x181483d0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"
}
```

Can anyone please help or atleast provide some directions?

To further give an insight, I'm using `OAuthConsumer` framework. Below are the lines of code where we place request to get an access token:

```
- (void)successfulAuthorizationWithToken:(NSString *)token verifier:(NSString *)verifier  {
    NSLog(@"successfulAuthorizationWithToken");
    OAMutableURLRequest *request;
    OADataFetcher *fetcher;

    //NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://vimeo.com/oauth/access_token"];
    request = [[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                               consumer:self.consumer
                                                  token:self.accessToken
                                                  realm:nil
                                      signatureProvider:nil autorelease];


    OARequestParameter *p0 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_token"
                                                                value:token];
    OARequestParameter *p1 = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier"
                                                                value:verifier];
    NSArray *params = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:p0, p1, nil];
    [request setParameters:params];

    fetcher = [[[OADataFetcher alloc] init] autorelease];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(accessTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];

    [p0 release];
    [p1 release];

}
```

I've also tried solutions specified in below link:
[Twitter API + OAuthConsumer.framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221083/twitter-api-oauthconsumer-framework)

It says to use `[[[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init] autorelease]` as `signatureProvider`. But the results are same.

I need to get following values after I get verifier and authorized token using the access token step:
`oauth_token=YourAuthorizedOauthToken&oauth_token_secret=YourAuthorizedTokenSecret`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. There were issues in the base string and oAuth Header string format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own callback in your request, which looks like `myapp://...` and register `myapp` handler in iOS, so that when browser is redirected then iOS will give control back to your app. I'm assuming you are using OAuth properly and start a browser from your app for user interaction. Alternatively you could use a WebView (not what OAuth recommends) then in the WebView delegate you can catch a redirect and parse `access toke` out.

Comment: I need to get oauth_token and oauth_token_secret using verifier and authorization token. I get verifier and authorization token after the second step "User Authorization" where app is redirected to callback url and I fetch verifier and authorization token from the request url in webview delegate method. But now I need to use these to get oauth_token and oauth_token_secret through the last step where I face the issues.

Comment: Well, I further researched, and I get an error: 401 Unauthorized - Invalid signature - The oauth_signature passed was not valid. My base signature key  is GET&http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Foauth%2Faccess_token&oauth_consumer_key%3D97823cb1ff039bce66966341928a7db2%26oauth_nonce%3DDEE0A217-620E-459A-8BF3-BE7F5B9F281A%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1305198917%26oauth_token%3Dd545d685bb6a38f9ce108c99b9175bbb%26oauth_verifier%3Dpulse-2088361215%26oauth_version%3D1.0    Can anyone tell where is the issue here?